# Getting date input from user and store it(python)

Tags: python-2.7

i have wrote a simple script to get inputs from user and store it in the database.
I also want date input but some problems are arising. 
First I have used datetime.date() function and passing the date but it is throwing some error.
I don't understand why?

```
import pyodbc
import datetime


class data:
       def __init__(self):
               self.name=raw_input( "Enter Name: ")
               self.section=raw_input( "Enter section: ")
               self.eon=datetime.date(1943,3, 13)  # This is in the requested 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.


a=data()
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=KIRAN-PC;DATABASE=testing')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Insert into Students (Name,Section,Enrol_On) Values (?,?,?)",(a.name,a.section,a.eon))
cnxn.commit()
```

Error:

```
 Enter Name: Tim
Enter section: A

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/data2.py", line 15, in <module>
    cursor.execute("Insert into Students (Name,Section,Enrol_On) Values (?,?,?)",(a.name,a.section,a.eon))
Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Optional feature not implemented (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the import from `from datetime import datetime` to `import datetime`. With your current code you import the class `datetime` from the module `datetime` and call the `date` method from this class with wrong parameters. But you want to call the constructor of the `date` class in the `datetime` module.

---

**Update to answer your edit**

According to https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=204:

> On Windows, you need to use DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0} for a driver that understands the ODBC date type.

Your current driver `SQL Server` does not understand how to pass the `date` datatype to your database.

You also have to pay attention that in your database the column `Enrol_On` is of type `SQL_TYPE_DATE`. See https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/DataTypes for the mapping of python datatypes to SQL types.

Comment: i am facing one more error now in the same code for storing date in databse as   " cursor.execute("Insert into Students (Name,Section,Enrol_On) Values (?,?,?)",(a.name,a.section,a.eon))          
Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Optional feature not implemented (0) (SQLBindParameter)')"

Comment: @user3201916 Updated my answer to adapt to your new question